# Laravel Eloquent : get data and use condition for related table column

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relation

I use `Laravel` and `Eloquent` and I want get data from two table via relation.

For example i want select all book in categories that category `status` is active.

```
class Book extends Model
{
    public $belongsTo  = [
        'category' => '..\Models\Categories',
    ];

    public function categories() {
        return $this->belongsTo('..\Models\Categories');
    }

}
```

In controller i can use next code for select all books.

```
Book::with('categories');
```

Is there way to select all book in categories that category `status` is active?

Comment: Can you make it clear, if book can belong to multiple categories or  single category?

Comment: book can belong to multiple categories

Comment: then definitely, you have a many-to-many relationship and not one-to-many .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use eager loading for this.

```
Book::with(['categories' => function($query){
    $query->where('status','active');
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Book extends Model
{
    /**
     * The categories that associated with the book.
     */
    public function categories()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Category');
    }
}
```

In category model you can define scope

like 
public function scopeStatus($query, $status='active') {
    $query->where('staatus', $status);
}

and you can retrieve as `$book->categories` and reverse is `$category->books`  and categories with books `Category::with('books')->status('active')->get()` .

Note: you need pivot table in this situation

Comment: @aya I have edited my answer, you can try this and let me know, if you are facing any issue with it?